# Install windows 7 on a hard-disk and use that to other system?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there any way to install windows 7 on a hard-drive of Computer `A` and unplug the hard-drive and uses that on Computer `B`?
when I tried for this showed me the blue screen and crashed! why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this sucessfully a lot, but you need to use sysprep.
yes.  If the hardware is not the same you need to use sysprep

First install on computer A
c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep /generalize /oobe /shutdown

When the computer turns off automatically then move the hard drive and turn computer B.
Sysprep will take up to 20 minutes to complete.

The reason this happens:   is the hard drive controllers are different and require different drivers.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the systems are identical, you're more than likely to run into trouble with conflicting drivers. I'm speculating, but I'd guess the BSOD is being caused by the storage controller or chipset driver. Be certain by booting into "Advanced Boot Options" (press F8 at boot), then disable automatic restart on system failure. Search the error produced.

Comment: won't work and show me the bluescreen again, thnx anyway and rep++ ;

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers are correct, and even sysprep can be a pain to the uninitiated...

That said, there is also a sort of [manual equivalent to sysprep,](http://forums.techguy.org/hardware/831811-moving-windows-install-swapping-motherboards.html) It is not fun or pretty, but it gives you better odds for moving to an unlike system than just moving the drive. Sysprep is the better choice, but this works too.